# How can I use comma in a webgrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I have a table containing numbers of type double I try to show those numbers in webgri but want those number are separated by a comma for example if my number is 125036.50 I want to show follows the WebGrid 125,036.50 someone I can give some idea of ​​how to do it

Comment: Are you sure that you want to display 125,036.50 and not 125.036,50 ? The latter is a standard way of displaying, your one is either very uncommon or does not exist at all.

Comment: Did you try to format your column in Webgrid?

Comment: @bejger That of course depends entirely on the culture information.

Answer (score 0):

Format your WebGrid column like this -

```
grid.Column("Quantity", format: @<text>@item.Quantity.ToString("#,##0.00")</text>)
```

Comment: @user3287881, are you able to solve your problem with my answer? Are you facing any other difficulties?